# How to write html tags under "contact details" in components > contact > contact us

Tags: administrator, form, contact, contact-form

Please visit this link : http://naadiastrology.info/index.php/contact-us

On the menu bar, you can see "Contact us" menu.[Components > Contacts> Contacts > Contact-us in admin ]

If you click on that, you can see:

"1Contact", "2contact form", "3Links" & "4other information".

Please click on "other information".

I wanted to display "1contact" as like "4other information page content".

But In admin, in right side, Under "contact details", there is no option to use "html tags".

But we can use html tags under "other information".

How to use "html tags" under "contact details" in right side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the direct answer to your question, it is more for information and to give you some basic direction.
It seems that you do not have full understanding of how things work, and why you can't add html in the fields there. 
The fields you are trying to add html, are not designed to accept html. Furthermore, even if they would allow some html, I am not sure how you could create a similar table structure like you did in the WYSIWYG editor for the misc information section.

However, you still have plenty of options to customize the way your contact page will look.

You could either use a 3rd party Form Component ([**Joomla Form Extensions**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms)) and build a custom form the way you want, or you could override the com_contact.

This search will bring you many relevant questions regarding overrides:

https://joomla.stackexchange.com/search?q=template+overrides 
Also the links here at Joomla Documentation:

1. [**How to override the output from the Joomla! core**](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)
2. [**Understanding Output Overrides**](http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides)
3. [**Layout Overrides in Joomla**](http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla)

Finally, you if you need to override the model form for the com_contact, to change the behavior of the current fields..., then this question/answer here might be of help of how to do this.

[How can I completely and safely remove the subject field in com_contact?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4426/how-can-i-completely-and-safely-remove-the-subject-field-in-com-contact/4427#4427)

Comment: hi, Thanks a lot for reply. I am new to joomla. Very nice explaination from you.... thanks for that.... Is there any extension to achieve this? or Is there any other easy way? please help me to find solution.

Comment: Better use a form component to set up a custom form. http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms

Comment: hi, i installed this : http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/16899 please guide me what next i have to do?

Comment: hi, installed a module : http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-modules/3668 , now i want to replace contact us menu by "blank module". how to do this?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. I created an article and just linked to the menu. you are just ultimate person. thanks for helping.....