# How can I remove the subject field in com_contact?

Tags: contact-form

Hey guys i just have the question how i could remove the name, subject or Message field at the contact form.

i know they are located in `/templates/.../html/com_contact/contact/default_form.php` but when i remove the fields just in the layout i couldn't send the form cause of the required fields.

Here you can find some more information where i got it from "[How can I completely and safely remove the subject field in com_contact?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4426/how-can-i-completely-and-safely-remove-the-subject-field-in-com-contact)

The probem is the file components/com_contact/models/forms/contact.xml doesnt have anymore the code for `contact_subject`. so anyone know how i could solve this with joomla 3.8?

Comment: Welcome to Joomla Stack Exchange. Just out of curiosity, why would you **want** to remove these fields?

Comment: i have afew contact forms at my webside for different things and i don't need everytime the subject field or message field. i like to customize the form by myself

Comment: Have you considered using a 3rd party extension which may be a little nore flexible?

Comment: Yes i could try another extension but than I have to rebuild all contact forms and that would be lots of work :/ i thought it would be easier to remove the default fields